# How Can we execute a Agi script after hangup

Tags: asterisk, voip

How Can we execute a Agi script after hangup ,Actually i am using queue with local channel, I m trying with "h,1,AGI()".but it is executing two times after hangup but i want to execute it one time after hangup of both channels

Comment: Can You provide diall plan of your queue, and how You enter them?

Answer (score 0):

Correct way - NEVER execute scripts after hangups. Use mysql or other db cdrs, put all info you need into cdrs using custom fields

```
exten => s,n,Set(CDR(my_db_custom_field)=something)
```

After call end check cdrs and execute needed action by EXTERNAL threads.

Asterisk h extensions designed for fast non-blocking actions only.

It will be executed only once. If you have twice, very likly you have more then 1 channel (Local/ channels) in your dialplan.

You have add h-extension only into ONE place(in case of queue only in agent call or better use queue_log action for queue)